# Blurry text at Safari

Tags: css, safari, linear-gradients

I'm having a bad time with this text gradient-colored.

I've been through some tuts that teach how to apply gradient to a dynamic text. It works, but Safari can't handle it well, it seems.

### Chrome rendering

[image]

### Safari rendering

[image]

Two problems: this line at the top of the element, looks like it is a bug with `-webkit-background-clip: text;`, But this problem is the lesser, cuz I can deal with it. The real problem is the blurry text, tho.

CSS

```
.title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: right;
    color: #981d97;
    display: block;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left ,#ffa300 0,#e31c79 50%,#981d97 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#ffa300 0,#e31c79 50%,#981d97 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d3vLd4ft/1/

## EDIT

- I've followed mcclaskiem's hint about changing `line-height` from `1em` to `50px` because it could be at a half-pixel height. **Didn't work**
- I've noticed that the font get slightly better while the browser is being resized, but once it stops, the font get blurry again.

Comment: I don't see a difference on my end. Are you using a display with high DPI?

Comment: A simple look at browserstack (from where i took the printscreen) will show you the diference between the rendered texts. If you are talking about the images i attached here, you can just click on them to see the image at natural resolution. You'll se the diference.

Comment: Could have something to do with the text being on a half pixel as a result of using em's for `line-height` which usually is a result of using a transform on elements. Try hardcoding the `line-height` to a whole number pixel amount and see if that helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is one trick that can make the browser accelerate graphics, it made the font look much better:

```
     -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
         -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
          -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
             transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
```

## The result:

From this

[image: Bad quality text]

It goes to this

[image: Good quality text]